# AngularJS injection not working with IE10

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have tested my AngularJS 1.4.2 application with different browsers and an error with IE 10 appeared (at bottom). With IE 9 it works fine and also with Chrome and Firefox it works fine.
Does anyone know what I can do in order to make it work with IE 10?

Thats the code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myproject.institutionmanagement')
    .controller('InstitutionManagementController', InstitutionManagementController);

InstitutionManagementController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal', 'currentUser', 'institutionManagementService', 'institutionsscheduleService', 'institutionService', 'institutionUserConnectionService', 'institutionUserConnectionsOfInstitutions', 'userScheduleManagementService', 'searchUserService', 'optionsService', 'dateCheckService'];

function InstitutionManagementController($scope, $modal, currentUser, institutionManagementService, institutionsscheduleService, institutionService, institutionUserConnectionService, institutionUserConnectionsOfInstitutions, userScheduleManagementService, searchUserService, optionsService, dateCheckService) {
    $scope.vm = this; 
    var vm = this;

...
```

[image: IE10Error]

Comment: You should probably use `angular.js` for debugging.

Comment: Actually I dont know how to debug angular.js. I only work with angular.js a few months.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. I had declared a function twice in my service. Chrome and Firefox ignores this fact but IE10 does not. 
Maybe this could help someone in the future.

```
function myService($http, api_config) {
    var service = {
        myFunction1 : myFunction1,
        myFunction1 : myFunction1
    };
```